# Bup not installed Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, backup

I need some help. My backup aren't working.
I checked my settings and it say`bup` is not installed on my computer.

[image]
[image]

***Update***

When I attempt to install `bup` package on commandline, I get an error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package bup is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bup' has no installation candidate
```

Also, I have tried the aptitude command:

```
sudo aptitude install bup              
No candidate version found for bup       
Unable to apply some actions, aborting
```

I wonder if these are package that need to be install on computer in order for me to install `bup`

```
krillavilla on  master [?] 
apt-cache search bup 
libupower-glib-dev - abstraction for power management - development files
libupower-glib3 - abstraction for power management - shared library
libupsclient-dev - network UPS tools - development files
libupsclient4 - network UPS tools - client library
libupb-dev - small protobuf implementation in C (development files)
libupb0 - small protobuf implementation in C
libupnp-dev - Portable SDK for UPnP Devices, version 1.8 (development files)
libupnp-doc - Documentation for the Portable SDK for UPnP Devices, version 1.8
libupnp-java - Java library for Universal Plug aNd Play (upnp)
libupnp-java-doc - Java library for Universal Plug aNd Play (upnp) - doc
libupnp13 - Portable SDK for UPnP Devices, version 1.8 (shared library)
libups-nut-perl - network UPS tools - Perl bindings for NUT server
libupse-dev - unix playstation sound emulator - library development files
libupse2 - unix playstation sound emulator - library
upse123 - commandline player based on libupse
uptimed - daemon to track uptimes, especially the high ones
```

Comment: (Not relevant to the question) You can just use sudo in terminal (it is safer) without using root.

Answer (score -1):

### Edit since bup does not install for you.

`bup` installs for me on Ubuntu MATE 22.04. It must be that either your sources are out of date, or you are using an outdated server hosting the repositories. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) question to restore default sources.

---

Once done, you can install `bup` with

```
sudo apt install bup
```

---

How I got to know the package name - I [searched](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bup) on packages.ubuntu.com.

Comment: This is error message:

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package bup is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bup' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt update` and try again?

Comment: same error message

Comment: Can you edit the question and add all these information?